# Android Checkbox - Background + Button Layout - wrong Size

Tags: android, layout, checkbox, shapes

I think I'm not seeing an error in one of my layouts. I want to display a Checkbox and and a border around it.

I generated the images using the [Android Holo Colors Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/)

I tried to add a shape to the checkbox, which worked fine on a Nexus 4, but did not display the button at all on any other device, so I added a dummy layout:

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3sp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_button" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:button="@drawable/btn_radio_holo_dark_hm" />
</LinearLayout>
```

shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="@color/gray" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5sp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5sp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5sp"
        android:topRightRadius="5sp" />

</shape>
```

Now I get this:

[image: Layout on Devices]

I tried setting minWidth depending on mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi but the button never looks centered on every device. fill_parent/wrap_content does not result in any change, also moving the button inside the layout.

Any suggestions on what has gone wrong here?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this?

Comment: No, I ended up removing the border.

Answer (score 4):

change your outer layout to a RelativeLayout and set centerInParent=true for checkbox

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
android:layout_marginTop="3sp"
android:background="@drawable/shape_button" 
android:padding="2sp">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/check"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:button="@drawable/btn_radio_holo_dark_hm" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this results in a button that stretches over as much space as available. If I set width and height to wrap_content I get the same result as with the LinearLayout.

Comment: set width/height as wrap_content in CheckBox. and set it fill_parent for RelativeLayout

Comment: same result, sorry. The rest of the layout is all wrap_content by the way, except the top parent.

Comment: if you can provide the whole layout, i might be able to provide a better solution

Comment: The layout is rather lengty :)

I just created a test activity that loads a layout with just these two elements, nothing else. The button looks the same.